# How do I provide optional generics as macro_rules arguments?

Tags: rust, macros, rust-macros

I want to use `macro_rules` to create an implementation for a trait. The types should be given as macro arguments. However, some of those types may contain lifetimes, so I need them. I also have a generic type from inside the macro. The result should look like

```
impl<T> Foo<T> for MyType { .. }
// Or with lifetime:
impl<'a, 'b, T> Foo<T> for LifetimeType<'a, 'b> { .. }
```

How do I structure the macro and how do I call it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `lifetime` specifier to match lifetimes in macro arguments:

```
trait Foo{}

macro_rules!impl_foo {
    ($($l:lifetime),*; $t:tt) => { impl<$($l),*> Foo for $t<$($l),*> {} };
    ($t:ty) => { impl Foo for $t {} };
}
```

And call it like this:

```
impl_foo!(A);
impl_foo!('a, 'b; B);
```

[Playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=80e92d010fe6bc89e19b3829f4789f47)

Note that the only place I could find that talked of the `lifetime` specifier for captures is [the associated RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1590). It is in particular conspicuously missing from [The little book of Rust macros](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/mbe-macro-rules.html#captures), even though it was merged in 2016…